# How do I turn off incoming video in Microsoft Teams Version 1.6.00.22378?

Tags: microsoft-teams

In the Windows desktop client, Microsoft has moved the option to turn off incoming video, again! Does anyone know where they've moved it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've now put it under View > More Options.

[image]